# Using .replace to remove certain letters

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, python-2.x

I would like to illiminate all instances of CA using .replace, when the letters CA appear alone, ie not part of a word.

but when I add .replace('ca', '')

Words such as America and American are also ignored because they contain ca

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this please ?

Thanks

ps I need to do this using python 27

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to remove them when it's a word by itself? Use a regular expression with `\b` word boundaries.

Comment: use replace(' ca ', ''), so only replace when ca is alone.

Comment: @Satya, OP already said they don't want to use that as that may not solve for all `ca` only items. Like Barmar said, reg ex with word boundary would be the best.

Comment: @joe, That's why i've added space around ' ca ',   But yes , regex one is better at handling few more cases like ca at the ending of the sentence(for example 'America ca replace ca').

Comment: @Satya, how would you solve for `ca is a state` or `my state is ca`

Comment: @joe, that's why i mentioned using regex boundary is a better choice,  still if you are insisting on how to solve , then  let's have a string which has all the possible pattern   s = 'ca is a ca state ca' ,  Now using replace method, try     s.replace(' ca ', ' ').replace(' ca', '').replace('ca ','')    and output is 'is a state'    which removes all the 'ca' pattern of your query.  So you can solve anything in pure python code,  behind regex some python string implementation is there, right? Yes,  i will still prefer regex boundary as it seems more intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
.replace('ca', '')
```

You should use `re` module

```
import re
re.sub(r"\bca\b", "", string_you_want_to_change)
```

By using the pattern `r"\bca\b"` instead of just `"ca"`, you ensure that you only match `"ca"` when it appears as a stand-alone word.